# IntelliJ Generate PHPDoc

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpdoc

In IntelliJ, you can generate JavaDoc by going to `Tools -> Generate JavDoc`. When you have a Static Web PHP project, however, JavaDoc will not work, throwing the error that no Java classes could be found.

Now, what I need is to generate actual PHPDoc. My functions and classes already have the necessary PHPDoc comments in the source code. How is it done, if it's at all possible without having to resort to PHPStorm?

I haven't been able to find the answer anywhere on StackOverflow or in the IntelliJ documentation. All I have found was how to have IntelliJ automatically generate the necessary PHPDoc comments based on the function signature, but what I wanna do is export them to standalone HTML files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Run -> Edit Configurations...** then add a new PHP script. In the **File** field, point to the location of `phpdoc` on your machine. In the **Arguments** field, add something like this, taking into account whatever extra arguments you may need:

```
-d /path/to/code -t /path/to/target/directory
```

Name the script, hit **OK** to save your changes, and you should be good to go. It'll be added to the dropdown of Run/Debug Configurations.